# Custom URL in Vite dev server (multi page app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm building a multi page app with [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) (migrating from Webpack).

To open the login page in the dev server I have to go to: `localhost:3010/login.html`

Is it possible to tweak the Vite config to serve login.html with the URL as: `localhost:3010/login` (without .html)?

```json
// vite.config.js excerpt

export default {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        index: new URL('./index.html', import.meta.url).pathname,
        login: new URL('./login.html', import.meta.url).pathname,
      }
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 3010,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:5000/',
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Configure the Vite dev server with a Vite plugin's [`configureServer(server)`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#configureserver) API. That method's `server` argument is a [`ViteDevServer`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-javascript.html#vitedevserver), whose `middlewares` property is the underlying [*Connect* instance](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect). Call [`middlewares.use()`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#appusefn) with a method that acts as a custom middleware.

Here's a basic plugin that configures the dev server to replace `/login` with `/login.html`, added to the [`plugins` array](https://vitejs.dev/config/#plugins) in the Vite config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

const LoginHtmlFallbackPlugin = {
  name: 'login-html-fallback',
  configureServer(server) {
    server.middlewares.use('/login', (req, res, next) => {
      req.url += '.html'
      next()
    })
  }
}

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    LoginHtmlFallbackPlugin
  ],
})
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-dev-server-html-fallback-ea9csb?file=vite.config.ts)

And a more dynamic plugin that falls back to a corresponding `.html` file (appending `.html` to extension-less URLs) only if it exists:

```js
// build/plugins/html-ext-fallback.js
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

export default (options) => ({
  name: 'html-ext-fallback',
  configureServer(server) {
    server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
      // Check extensionless URLs but ignore the `/` root path
      if (req.originalUrl.length > 1 && !path.extname(req.originalUrl)) {
        if (fs.existsSync(path.join(options.rootDir, `${req.originalUrl}.html`))) {
          req.url += '.html'
        }
      }
      next()
    })
  }
})

// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import HtmlExtFallbackPlugin from './build/plugins/html-ext-fallback'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    HtmlExtFallbackPlugin({ rootDir: __dirname })
  ],
})
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-dev-server-html-fallback?file=vite.config.ts)

Comment: I noticed that this solution breaks the Vite HMR when accessing `/page-name`, but `/page-name.html` still works (the content is refreshed when you save the code in the `page-name.html` file). Do you know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As Rafael pointed out, rewriting the URL breaks the HMR feature for that page. Using a redirect, however, does not:

```
//req.url += '.html'
res.writeHead(301, { Location: `${req.url}.html` })
```

You will get an "ugly" URL during development, but you can revert to URL rewriting on your production server (since HMR would not be needed then).