# How to define custom Express.js route for vite dev server

Tags: javascript, webpack, vite

I am translating my app from webpack configuration into vite. My current webpack dev server has custom endopint configured for doing some stuff. I need to have this same endpoint in vite config as well. How to do this? How can I define an express.js route for vite dev server?

This endpoint is for loading environment variables from a service during runtime. The url for this route is `/__variables.js`.

I tried using [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078675/custom-url-in-vite-dev-server-multi-page-app) code

```
server.middlewares.use('/__variables.js', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('hello we"re here')
  console.log(err, req, res)
  const variables = Object.keys(process.env).reduce(
      (prev, key) => {
          if(key.startsWith('REACT_APP_')) {
              prev[key] = process.env[key];
          }

          return prev;
      }
  , {});
  res
      .status(200)
      .type('.js')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript')
      .send(`window.__APP_VARIABLES__ = ${JSON.stringify(variables)}`)
  next();
});
```

but this throws an error `res.status() is not a function`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`ViteDevServer`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-javascript.html#vitedevserver), it's based on Connect, not (as you seem to assume) Express, which means you can't use any of the useful shortcut methods that Express provides on the request and response objects.

Instead, `req` will be an instance of [`http.ClientRequest`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest) and `res` an instance of [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserverresponse).

Your Express-ish code will translate to this:

```
res
  .writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/javascript' })
  .end(`window.__APP_VARIABLES__ = ${JSON.stringify(variables)}`);
```